# Make the Codeblock detection less aggressive

Tags: bug, stackexchange, editor

In this question [Small Bayes Calculator to learn Javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/273248/229565) I ended up adding a maths appendix with a bunch of LaTeX. This LaTeX was detected as "code" and I was supposed to indent it by 4 spaces otherwise it would not let me post it. Indenting it would have prevented it from rendering the equations though, so I worked around this issue by making a picture of the *perfectly fine* preview and added this at the end instead of the LaTeX formulas.

The codeblock detection algorithm should either be taught LaTeX or be possible to override.

EDIT: still does not work
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The codeblock detection that you ran into has been [active on Code Review since 2011](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/337/37660). If [the documentation for that particular check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98432/222299) is still up to date, the following restrictions apply:

> This check is limited to users with <= 50 reputation and is performed on questions / answers / edits and suggested edits.

Since you have earned an association bonus and were caught either way, I presume the check does not include association bonus rep in the threshold calculation.

If you attempt to submit the same LaTeX (note that codereview has a special delimiter for it), it should work now.

Comment: so instead of `$$` I should use...?

Comment: Perhaps the check is gained over 50 reputation, as both 151 and 51 don't allow Felix to post the MathJax. Or mutated to something else later.

Comment: @FelixB. if the LaTeX renders, it's the correct delimiters. I think for inline latex CodeReview has `\$` instead of `$`

Comment: @Vogel612 ah, that is why the inline tex did not work (I just worked around that)

Comment: I tried to add `\$` to the one inline formula I kept (in plain text) and I still can not submit this edit. So it is not like the reputation check is only updated every day or something.